# Combining Discrete Choice Experiments with Theory of Planned Behavior

Tags: experimental-psychology, behavior, behavioral-economics

Topic background: How beliefs and personal values of a farmer influence his/her willingness to consider/adopt environmentally friendly innovations on-farm.

I want to assess if relative **preferences** for given attributes of a presented technology (as assesd in Discrete Choice Experiments - DCE) can be used/included into the Theory of Planned Behavior (TPB) to assess the **intention to adopt** a this technology. In other words: Can I combine DCEs with TPB?